# Java: Coloring output in Windows

Tags: java, jansi

In a program I'm making, I really want to change the color of some words in my output. Thing is, the only solution I've found is [Jansi](https://github.com/fusesource/jansi), but honestly I'm very new to Github and this kind of projects and I have no idea about how to import it, or using it in my project.

So, is there any kind of alternative method to color some words in my Windows console? Or is Jansi my only option? In that case, can someone enlighten me about how to use it in my project?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you'd read the description on the repository, you would have found the [release downloads](http://fusesource.github.io/jansi/download.html) link. Just add the most recent one of those to your project like any other .jar

Answer (score -1):

As an easiest solution you can just copy `Ansi.class` from [Jansi](https://github.com/fusesource/jansi) to your project.

See an example of usage [here](https://github.com/ASaunin/sandbox-java/blob/3c9a3e4682fc0e272f1b20f41f98bb9f0ec3dad6/concurrency/src/main/java/executors/scheduled/Ticker.java)

But actually [Socratic Phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4484294/socratic-phoenix) is right. Better way is to add it as a jar library to your project.